# No sound after logging in

Tags: sound, 18.04, pulseaudio, alsa

I'm using an Asus Transformer Book TH101.

While I'm on the login screen, I'm able to adjust the volume properly and can even hear the corresponding beeps. But after I login I'm no longer able to adjust the volume. As you can see in the screenshot below, the slider is completely grayed out.

[image: Screenshot]

I've tried reinstalling `pulseaudio`, and when I run `pulseaudio --start` I get

```
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.
```

And when I run `alsamixer`, I get

```
This sound device does not have any controls.
```

I'd really appreciate some help with fixing this problem.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: The latest one 18.04.1 lts.Maybe it is something with my device?

Comment: The netbook came today with windows 10 installed and the sound worked properly,but i really do not like windows at all so i wanted to install ubuntu on it.

Answer (score 1):

This answer comes late but maybe it will help someone else.

I had the same issue after installing and removing pulseaudio-equalizer.
I could control sound (input + output) just fine however after login neither input by keyboard or the settings would work and the sound-interface wouldnt show any devices just like you described.

The issue was it had changed a config file from pulseaudio.

Renaming it and having it regenerated after a reboot fixed the issue for me:

```
mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/old_pulse
reboot
```

("~" points to your users home directory)

If that didnt fix your issue you may want to change it back to your old config:

```
rm ~/.config/pulse
mv ~/.config/old_pulse ~/.config/pulse
```

This is not my solution. I found it on: It's FOSS - https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/